# Django how to change bounds value of IntegerRangeField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have model with ***IntegerRangeField*** in it, which returns data as, for example,  ***NumericRange(1992, 1997, '[)')*** after adding objects to the database. I need second option of range to be also included in it, so the bounds should be like *'[]'*.
I was looking for the solution in the [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#adapt-range), but unfortunatelly didn't find an answer.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

My current *models.py*

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField
from django.contrib.postgres.validators import RangeMinValueValidator, RangeMaxValueValidator
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Bancnote(models.Model):

    Dollar= 'Dollar'
    Euro= 'Euro'

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (Dollar, 'Dollar'),
        (Euro, 'Euro')
    )

    type = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=Dollar)
    par = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year = IntegerRangeField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    sign = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bons_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.par) + ' ' + self.type + ' ' + str(self.year.lower) + '-' + str(self.year.upper)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#integerrangefield) says:

> Regardless of the bounds specified when saving the data, PostgreSQL
>   always returns a range in a canonical form that includes the lower
>   bound and excludes the upper bound; that is [).

So I'm afraid you can't really change that. You can however store the data as usual:

```
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange

Bancnote.objects.create(
    # specify other fields
    year=NumericRange(1992, 1997, bounds='[]')
)
# assuming the object we created is with id=1
bancnote = Bancnote.objects.get(id=1)
print(bancnote.year) # NumericRange(1992, 1998, '[)')
```

which I suppose you do. It's not much of a help, but that's all I can contribute.

Comment: Looks like this might be changing soon for some types of range fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields